# How can I get FetchContent to download to a specific location?

Tags: cmake

Following the [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) documentation, e.g. using something like

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    gitache_package_libcwd_r
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/CarloWood/libcwd.git"
    GIT_TAG "master"
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(
    gitache_package_libcwd_r
)
```

The source code is cloned into `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/gitache_package_libcwd_r-src/`.

How can I make it put the source code elsewhere, like `/opt/gitache/libcwd_r/src/gitache_package_libcwd_r` (as it would be when I'd be using `ExternalProject` with a `PREFIX` of `/opt/gitache/libcwd_r`)?

Comment: You may try to set `SOURCE_DIR` parameter for `FetchContent_Declare`. This parameter works for `ExternalProject_Add`, so it would probably work for `FetchContent_Declare`, which is its wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles on this question looking for an answer, I found that at least it *is* possible to replace the `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps"` part by setting `FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR` before the call to `FetchContent_Declare`. I'm not sure if more fine tuned manipulation is possible or not. It seems possible, if you use the extended version of [FetchContent_Populate](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#populating-the-content), but using that has several drawbacks imho.

For example

```
set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR "/opt/gitache/libcwd_r")
FetchContent_Declare(... etc (see question)
```

will clone into `/opt/gitache/libcwd_r/gitache_package_libcwd_r-src/` and use
`/opt/gitache/libcwd_r/gitache_package_libcwd_r-build` as build directory.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the options `DOWNLOAD_DIR`, `SOURCE_DIR`, `TMP_DIR`, etc. as you would with [`ExternalProject_Add()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Cmake [FetchContent_Declare Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_declare):

> The `<contentOptions>` can be any of the download, update or patch options that the `ExternalProject_Add()` command understands. The configure, build, install and test steps are explicitly disabled and therefore options related to them will be ignored. The SOURCE_SUBDIR option is an exception, see `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` for details on how that affects behavior.